# Listing tables and their structure

Tags: t-sql, get, structure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing Table's structure/schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549799/printing-tables-structure-schema)
>   [oracle has 'DESCRIBE' to get all the details of the table like wise does t/sql has any thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177586/oracle-has-describe-to-get-all-the-details-of-the-table-like-wise-does-t-sql-h)

I want to get list of my tables with their structure.
Suppose I have 20 or more than .
How can I do it?
This query get me list of tables:

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
```

but 
I want  this

```
   Name    Structure


   Product        ID int Primary key,Name nvarchar(50),...........
   Group          ID int Primary key, Name nvarchar(50),..........
   Employee       ID int Primary Key,Name nvarchar(50), Address (300), ........
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
sp_columns tablename
```